# On Click event for command button doesn't update for different records in same form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a command button on a form which opens a separate form to only a new record that matches the Contact ID of the current form. This second form exists so I can establish a relationship between my contact and a new group, which is a one-to-many relationship as each contact can be in more than one groups, but some contacts aren't in any group.

Some users will be assigning existing contacts to a new group, and some users will be adding new contacts to an existing group, so I want the form establishing relationships between contacts and groups to exist independently from either the contacts form or the groups form. This is why I didn't simply create a subform on the contacts form. I don't know which direction my users will be coming from when editing relationships, and ideally I'd like to set up a system where the form the user is coming from will create a new record with one of the two fields (contact and group) auto-populated depending on the "parent" form. That is, if my user is accessing the relationships form from a contact form, I will see a new record with the ContactID filled in and I can select a group. Similarly, if a user is accessing the relationships form from a group form, that group will be filled in and the user will select a contact.

I have the following subroutine On Click of my command button on the contacts form:

```
Private Sub CmdAssignContactGroup_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContacts_Groups", , , , acFormPropertySettings
    [Forms]![frmContacts_Groups]![ContactID] = [Forms]![frmContacts]![ContactID]
End Sub
```

This works for any one contact, but when I move to a different contact without closing the contact form, the filter criteria remain the same and the command button brings me to the record in the contacts/groups form attached to the previous contact.

How can I tell the command button to reset after I change records within the contact form?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I didn't want to use a subform since I want it to also be possible to access `frmContacts_Groups` from the groups form. Essentially I want that to do the inverse- auto-populate group ID rather than contact ID on open. (Some users will be entering relationships into this form when a new group is created which may contain existing contacts, but some will be entering relationships when a new contact joins an existing group so this covers both cases.) There is no other code on events of this command button. I could use `Me` but I'm not sure it makes a difference here.

Comment: Most questions unanswered:( Does the form open with a new empty record? if not the first records `ContactID` will be changed to current `ContactID` of  `[Forms]![frmContacts]`. You want to be able to assign a new contact to serveral groups (when `CmdAssignContactGroup_Click` is used)  and assign serveral users to a new created group in the same form? The advantages of `Me `are 1. just two letters, 2. faster than a lookup in the `Forms`-Collection, 3. self explaining reference, 4. multi-instance save ( that's why I ask about how `frmContacts_Groups` is opened).

Comment: OK, a subform makes it unnecessary complicated! the trick is passing the form from where `frmContacts_Groups` was opened and using the `DefaultValue` property of the control that should have the ID of the opening form. If  frmContacts` has opened it the control (ComboBox?) that contains `ContactID`  of the Contacts_Group table gets the ID from the form as `DefaultValue` ,it gets locked to prevent changes and `frmContacts_Groups` is filtered to it. the same for the groups form with the `GroupID`, the name of the opening form is provided by ÒpenArgs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses the `DefaultValue` and the `Locked` property of a Control to pin the `ContactID` (if form is opened by `frmContacts`) or the `GroupID` (if form is opened by `frmGroups`) to the opening form values.

I assume two ComboBoxes in `frmContacts_Groups` that are bound to their `ID`s, but display the names of Client/Group, named `cboContactID`  and `cboGroupID`.

Code in `frmContacts_Groups`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim OpeningID As Long

  Select Case Me.Openargs
    Case "frmContacts"
      OpeningID = Nz(Forms!frmContacts!ContactID,0)  ' Nz to prevent errors on empty opening form
      Me.Filter = "ContactID = " & OpeningID
      Me.cboContactID.DefaultValue = OpeningID
      Me.cboContactID.Locked = True
      Me.cboGroupID.DefaultValue = vbNullString
      Me.cboGroupID.Locked = False
    Case "frmGroups"
      OpeningID = Nz(Forms!frmGroups!GroupID,0)
      Me.Filter = "GroupID = " & OpeningID
      Me.cboContactID.DefaultValue = vbNullString
      Me.cboContactID.Locked = False 
      Me.cboGroupID.DefaultValue = OpeningID
      Me.cboGroupID.Locked =True 
    Case Else
      Me.cboContactID.DefaultValue = vbNullString
      Me.cboContactID.Locked = False 
      Me.cboGroupID.DefaultValue = vbNullString
      Me.cboGroupID.Locked =False
      Me.Filter = vbNullString
   End Select
   Me.FilterOn = Len(Me.Filter) > 0
End Sub
```

Code for opening in `frmContacts`:

```
Private Sub CmdAssignContactGroup_Click()
  If Not CurrentProject.AllForms("frmContacts_Groups").IsLoaded then
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmContacts_Groups", OpenArgs:="frmContacts"
  Else
    Msgbox "frmContacts_Groups is allready opened! What should we do?"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the case statements using `Case "frmContacts"` and `Case "frmGroups"`- in the debugger, I am seeing this code skip to `Case Else` even when I am opening `frmContacts_Groups` from `frmContacts`.

Comment: Sorry missed a comma in `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContacts_Groups"`, but this should raise a `Type mismatch`

Comment: I had forgotten to change the `"frmContacts"` string to match my actual form name in the command button code but had changed it in my `Form_Load()` subroutine. Also I used `OpenArgs:=` because I don't like counting commas which is why the type mismatch didn't occur. This solution is working for me now, thanks!

Comment: Hopefully, this was a lesson to me giving up that bad habbit!

Answer (score 0):

Your where-condition does not relate to the form to be opened but to the currently open form, as you reference `ContactID` with `[Forms]![frmContacts_Groups]![ContactID]`. I.e. you pass the result of the comparison of the currently open forms (`True` or `False`) instead of passing a condition that will be evaluated by the opening form.

You must pass it a condition as text like `"ContactID = 10"`.

```
Dim condition As String

condition = "ContactID = " & Me!ContactID
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContacts_Groups", WhereCondition:=condition
```

Since `ContactID` is on the same Form, you can access it with `Me!ContactID`. It also looks like you are erroneously passing the condition as the `WindowMode` parameter.

Also make sure the properties of the `frmContacts_Groups` Form are

```
AllowEdits = Yes
AllowDeletions = No
AllowAdditions = No
```

and most important!

```
DataEntry = No
```

If `DataEntry` is `Yes`, then the form will jump to the new record!

Before opening the form, you could also call

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmContacts_Groups"
```

to make sure the previous edits of a possibly still open form do not interfere with the new edits.

Comment: I updated my sub as per your recommendations and I am still having the same problem. If I assign a new group to Smith, close the contacts-groups form, and move on to Doe's record, then click the command button from Doe's record, I still get a form to enter new contact-group assignments for Smith. I know the issue is not my contact ID on the contact form, because I have that value displayed and it changes appropriately between records.

Comment: `[Forms]![frmContacts_Groups]![ContactID] = [Forms]![frmContacts]![ContactID]` is not the WhereCondtion, it's new line. I guess OP wants to create  a new rocord and sets it's `ContactID` to current of `frmContacts`. Maybe instead if a new record the first record of the forms recordsource is loaded and its `ContactID` changed.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher. Probably you are right. Still not very clear what the OP wants. I usually pass information for new records (like ContactID) as OpenArgs.

Comment: Yes, I want to create a new record and set the `ContactID` to the current contact ID of `frmContacts`. I have been playing with OpenArgs, but I get an error message that "You can't assign a value to this field" when passing the ContactID value to frmContacts_Sites.

Comment: You would pass `OpenAgs

Comment: You would pass `OpenArgs` as parameter in `DoCmd.OpenForm`. To add a new Record, open the Form with `DoCmd.OpenForm FormName, DataMode:=acFormAdd`. Otherwise it will open an existing record and your code will overwrite it.

Comment: I have already tried passing `OpenArgs` as a parameter in `DoCmd.OpenForm` on the `frmContacts_Groups` and using `acFormAdd` when opening the form. I also have a subroutine on `Form_Open` for `frmContacts_Groups` to set `ContactID.Value = Me.OpenArgs` if `Me.OpenArgs` is not null. The error I described occurs with these settings in place, the problem is that `ContactID` is one of 2 primary keys on `frmContacts_Sites` and therefore cannot be assigned a value via `OpenArgs`.

Comment: It has to be a foreign key and must not be a Autonumber in child tables. If `ContactID` is a Autonumber in Contacts, then the corresponding column in child tables must be a Number Long Integer You should be able to set it for new records.

Comment: `ContactID` is not an autonumber in the child table `frmContacts_Groups` and is already set as type long integer. There is a one-to-many relationship between the two tables in the relationships tab on the `ContactID` field. In `frmContacts_Groups` I have both `ContactID` and `GroupID` set as primary keys (so I know each contact/ group relationship is unique) of type long integer. The fields are both autonumbers in parent tables.

Comment: Whether it is set via `Me.OpenArgs` or not should not make any difference. Does the value in OpenArgs have the right type (Long)? What I often do is to use invisible TextBoxes bound to the IDs, and instead of setting the IDs directly, I set the DefaultValue property of the TextBoxes. This way no empty record is created if the user enters nothing. But when the user enters anything the default values become effective.